# Finding the equation of a line that splits the area in half

Tags: calculus

I came across a question which I couldn't find the answer to and need some help with.

So there is a parabola of $~y=-3x^2 + 18x -15~$ which is bound by the $~x-~$axis.
Find the equation of the line $~y=mx+c~$ that goes through $~(1,0)~$ so that it splits the area of the parabola into $~2~$ equal parts.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Using the help below I still don't seem to be able to get it as I got h= to about 1.1094 which doesn't seem like its splitting the area of the parabola into 2 equal parts

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please let us know by editing the question text what you tried so far, in particular anything you had difficulty with, plus possibly other context such as where the question comes from. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The total area enclosed by the parabola and the $x$-axis is

$$\int_1^5 (-3x^2+18x-15)dx = 32$$

Assume the line intersects the parabola at (a,b). Then, the area above the line and under the parabola should be half of 32, i.e.

$$\int_1^a (-3x^2+18x-15)dx - \frac{1}{2}(a-1)b = 16\tag{1}$$

Carry out the integral

$$\int_1^a (-3x^2+18x-15)dx = (7-a)(a-1)^2\tag{2}$$

Plugging (2) and the replacement $b=3(5-a)(a-1)$ into (1) leads to a clean equation for $a$

$$ (a-1)^3=32$$

and the solution

$$a = 1+2^{5/3}$$

Correspondingly, $b=24(2^{2/3}-2^{1/3})$. Then, it is straightforward to find the equation of the line

$$y=6(2-2^{2/3})(x-1)$$

Answer (score 1):

Let the other point of intersection be $(h,k)$

So the equation of the line is $y-0 = \frac{k-0}{h-1}(x-1) \implies y = \frac{k(x-1)}{h-1} $

As we have equal areas,

[image]

$$\int^h_1\big[(-3x^2+18x-15) -\frac{k(x-1)}{h-1}\big]dx   = \int^h_1\big[\frac{k(x-1)}{h-1} - 0\big]dx + \int^5_h\big[(-3x^2+18x-15) - 0\big]dx$$

From this you'll get a relation between $h$ and $k$. Also $(h,k)$ lies on the parabola.

So, $k = -3h^2+18h-15$

On solving these equations you'll get $h$ and $k$

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, just wondering though, I got h to be about 1.1094 which when you join that with a line going through (1,0) doesn't seem like it would split the area of the parabola in 2 equal parts so have I gone wrong or misunderstood something? thanks.

Comment: @Bowie There was a typo. I used $k$ instead of $h$. You may find now.

Answer (score 1):

Start off by finding where the parabola intersects the $x$-axis and the resulting area. I assume that you know how to do this, so I’ll just present the answers: $x=1$ and $x=5$, with area equal to $32$.

An equation of a line through $(1,0)$ with slope $m$ is $y=m(x-1)$, so we find that $c=-m$ after virtually no work. Solving the system of equations, which again I assume you know how to do, gives the other intersection point of this line with the parabola: $(x_1,y_1) = \left(\frac{15-m}3,-\frac13m(m-12)\right)$.

Here I’ll depart from other answers. Instead of setting up an integral to find the area bounded by the parabola and this chord, I’ll use a handy property of parabolas: The area enclosed by a parabola and its chord is equal to two-thirds of the area of the bounding paralellogram (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Area_enclosed_between_a_parabola_and_a_chord) for details). Differentiating and solving for $x$ gives $x=3-\frac m6$ as the point at which the tangent to the parabola has slope $m$ and the equation of this tangent works out to be $$y=mx+\left(\frac{m^2}{12}-3m+12\right).$$ Subtracting the two $y$-intercepts produces $\frac1{12}(m-12)^2$, which is the length of the vertical sides of the bounding paralellogram, so the area bounded by the chord is $$\frac23 \left(\frac{15-m}3-1\right)\frac1{12}(m-12)^2 = \frac1{54}(12-m)^3.$$ Setting this equal to half the area computed previously results in the equation $(12-m)^3 = 864$. I’ll leave solving that to you.